# How to create thousands of endpoints for a post or a page or a custom post type programatically?

Tags: permalinks

Need help working with Wordpress endpoints with programming to create thousands of them like:

```
example. com/custom-pagepost-id/endpoint123
example. com/custom-pagepost-id/endpoint124
example. com/custom-pagepost-id/endpoint125
example. com/custom-pagepost-id/endpoint126
example. com/custom-pagepost-id/endpoint127
```

Comment: What you're calling endpoints, are actually url slugs for posts. When you create a new custom post, these slugs will be automatically created for you. You do not need to explicitly create them. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde there is nothing in the question to suggest that the endpoints are slugs in this case

Comment: Right, I wasn't very clear on what he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question if you actually want the word/number structure or you merely use numbers to distinguish endpoints as different.

Natively in WordPress there is no concept of endpoint with variable name. You can use [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to create a `endpoint` endpoint, which will match requests like `.../endpoint/123`, `.../endpoint/124`, and so on to convert them into `endpoint=123` query variable (where left name part is fixed and right value part is variable).

If you only want the variable part (without the fixed name preceding it) it won't be endpoint as WP understands it. You might still be able to achieve it by constructing completely custom rewrite rule, using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). However that will be more challenging and less reliable, especially with structures that have few elements and can easily interfere with native  rewrite rules.